# Refuse to execute Script when Including JS-Libraries in Thymeleaf Template

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I want to use JQuery and JSEncrypt in my Thymeleaf Page.
From researching I've found that I can achieve this with including the .js files of the libs that are saved in my /static/js/ folder of the spring boot application.

I get the following error:

[image]

FolderTree:

[image: Directory-tree of Spring Application]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<html ..>
..
..   
<link href="../static/css/layout.css" th:href="@{css/layout.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jsencrypt.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function encryptPw() {
        var encPw = $('#password').val();
        console.log(encPw);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form ...>
...
...
 <p>
     <label for="password" class="login-hidden-label">Passwort</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="login-input-field" placeholder="Passwort" required>
 </p>
    <button class="login-accept-button" onclick="encryptPassword()" type="submit">Anmelden</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by allowing all Requests in the spring web security for

```
/js/**
```

in my antMatchers.

```
httpSecurity.antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll();
```

fixes it.